# Rspec test describing listing items on index failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, kaminari

Rspec/TDD beginner. I have a spec that is failing and I don't know why. Everything works in the browser as it should. I am using Kaminari for pagination, which defaults to 25 items per page.

spec:

```
describe "Question Pages" do

    subject { page }

    describe "index page" do

        before { visit questions_path }
        before { 25.times { FactoryGirl.create(:question) } }
        after { Question.delete_all }
        it { should have_selector('h1', 'All Questions') }

        it "should list the questions" do
            Question.page(1).each do |question|
                page.should have_link(question.title, href: question_path(question))
            end
        end
    end
end
```

failure:

```
 1) Question Pages index page should list the questions
     Failure/Error: page.should have_link(question.title, href: question_path(question))
     Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
       expected to find link "Lorem Ipsum 33" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/features/question_pages_spec.rb:17:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/features/question_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why is it failing on item number 33 when I told it to make 25?

factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :question do
        sequence(:title) { |i| "Lorem Ipsum #{i}" }
        body "Dolor sit amet"
        passed false
    end
end
```

view:

```
<h1>All Questions</h1>
 <%= paginate @questions %>
 <ul class="questions">
     <% @questions.each do |question| %>
          <li>
             <section class="question_<%= question.id %> clearfix">
                 <h2><%= link_to truncate(question.title, length: 62), question_path(question) %></h2>
                 <p><%= truncate(question.body, length: 70) %></p>

          </li>
      <% end %>
 </ul>
```

controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @questions = Question.page(params[:page])
    end
end
```

ruby 1.9.3p429, rails 3.2.13, rspec-rails 2.13.1, capybara 2.1.0,  kaminari 0.14.1, faker 1.0.1, factory_girl_rails 4.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you ensure that you are creating factories before visit ?

Maybe something like instead of

```
before { visit questions_path }
before { 25.times { FactoryGirl.create(:question) } }
```

that

```
before do 
  25.times { FactoryGirl.create(:question) }
  visit questions_path 
end
```

If it will not help maybe you can display content of page?

```
puts page.inspect
```

Comment: putting both statements inside a before block worked. Thanks! any idea as to why the original syntax didn't work? @lis2

Comment: In the first example, the questions are created after questions_path is visited, so questions aren't there when the page renders. In the second, the questions are created (correctly) before the page is visited so capybara is able find the selectors.